# Is there a way to get Balgruff to keep the axe of war?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So, thinking of doing the stormcloak questline, but I really do like Jarl Balgruff, he's cool. Thing is, despite being a thalmor hater, and talos worshipper himself, he still gives the axe back and you're forced to invade Whiterun and depose him. Is there a way to stop that decision and get him to keep the axe, thus joining the stormcloak cause without bloodshed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there isn't. Balgruf will continue to support the Empire no matter what.

Comment: Well... damn. Was hoping there was some way to fix that without a mod.